# Is there a way to solve $a^{x}=x$ analytically?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm trying to find the zeros of $f(n)=n-8\log_{2}(n)$

I am stuck trying to solve $2^{\frac{n}{8}}=n$ analytically.

Am I forgetting some exponential rule or some algebraic method here?

The only way I could do it by hand was using Newton's method after taking a look at the graph and using n=42 as my first guess.

Comment: You can get closer by moving the terms around to $\sqrt[8]{2}=\sqrt[n]{n}$.  Then you can work with $\sqrt[8]{2}=\sqrt[16]{4}=\sqrt[32]{16}=\sqrt[64]{256}$..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function

Comment: No, there is no easy manipulation to get an exact answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Real solutions:
$$- \frac{8}{\ln(2)}  W(-\ln(2)/8)$$
where $W$ is either the "$0$" or the "$-1$" branch of the Lambert W functions.

Approximate numerical values: $1.099997030$ and $43.55926044$.

Comment: It should be noted that using the $W$ 'function' is just giving a different name to the solutions.

Comment: @YoTengoUnLCD No more so than using any other special function.

Comment: Well, it's obvious that the OP wants to get 'the numbers' analytically, and this just says "you'll have to go numerical" in disguise, which is misleading, in my opinion.

Comment: @RobertIsrael I just looked up this Lambert W function up and worked through an example which used newtons method to solve it. So how do I know when there is no way to do it analytically?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I agree with you regarding the use of $W$ as no different from use of any other well-known special function.  In fact, I don't see a difference from its use and use of "ordinary" functions such as trigonometric ones.  So (+1).

Comment: @speespa What do you mean by "do it analytically"?  Is the Lambert W function not already analytic over its branches?